# PHP MySQL Update after Seconds

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update a MySQL field after when the site was opened for X Seconds.
I get the Seconds/Time from MySQL and want to update in MySQL when the seconds are over.

I tried

```
sleep($adddisplaytime);
```

but then the site waits complete and does not run the things over first

Is there a way to run my update after some seconds when the site is opened?

```
$query1 = "UPDATE ads SET views = views+1, costs = costs+price WHERE id = '".$adid."'";
```

Can be in PHP or MySQL

Comment: You would need javascript for this.

Comment: Unfortunately this can't be done with PHP alone, you will need to allow the website to load and then us Javascript to count and then send an AJAX request to do the views / cost update.

Comment: Do not use anything client-side (like JS) to determine or trigger charges assessed against the user, or the user can simply avoid/edit the charge. What you want to do can be done with PHP alone. To do it as described, when the page is first rendered, you'd have to queue a background job tied to that session. The background job would then fire at some point in the future, performing the update query. Or you could simply store the start time in the user's session and then assess the charges on subsequent page loads by calculating the time difference.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Using [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) with jQuery you can launch a request ten seconds after opening the page if that's your intent. Have some kind of "viewed" endpoint. Remember to **secure your increment function** by issuing some kind of signature that can be verified to limit this to one view and one view only. If you don't someone's sure to "test" your page and crank up billions of fake page views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE: This will do what you want, but could be exploited by someone hitting the AJAX endpoint repeatedly, you would want to build in some protections for that.**

You will need an additional PHP file, the job of that PHP is to only update the db. You will need to take that update OUT of your page loading script.

**Your HTML / JS / PHP for initial load**

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax('/your/ajax/endpoint.php', {
        data: {
            'adid': 'your id'
            /*
               If this is in your PHP file, you can echo the ID straight there.
               Not totally recommended, but that's one way An additional / 
               better way is to add it to a div with a data attribute and 
               use jQuery to select the data off of there
            */
        }
    }); // Probably lots more you can do here, but in this case, for simplicity, just sending and that's it
}, 2000); // This will do a 2 second wait
</script>
```

**Your new additional PHP file that is at /your/ajax/endpoint.php**

```
<?php
// THIS FILE DOES THE UPDATE
$adid = $_POST['adid'];

// As mentioned by tadman in his comment.. I would use prepared statements 
$query1 = "UPDATE ads SET views = views+1, costs = costs+price WHERE id = ?";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($query1);
    $sth->execute(array($adid));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**NOTE:**

Again, for security's sake, you really want to consider having your first PHP script generate a unique ID (and store it in the db), that is passed to the page, and having the AJAX send that unique ID with the adid, and if the unique ID you gave is in the database only THEN would you know it's a legitimate request. Remove the unique ID from the database and do the update.

Comment: Thanks!
I save a securenumber in SESSION and save that with PHP in MySQL. On the AJAX PHP endpoint check the SESSION SECURENUMBER and validate with the adid number if there is the same :) Works perfectly :)

My only Problem now, i delete that securenumber on the endpoint from the mysql... but if a user reload the site before the timer, its in the mysql forever when he not jumped into the endpoint

Answer (score -2):

If you want to wait for some seconds after a page is opened and then run the update statement , then write the following codes on the top of the page:-

```
echo "<script> setTimeout(function(){}, 2000) ; </script>" ;

$query1 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE ads SET views = views+1, costs = costs+price WHERE id = '".$adid."'");
```

Comment: This will run the query immediately. PHP isn't going to wait for the remote browser to maybe run some JS before it executes the next line of code.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't run server-side. That timeout function literally does nothing.